# Loop over infinite nested dicts in Python

Tags: python

I have a data structure in Python which can have infinite nested dicts and lists, this is a mock-up:

```
payload={
   "mimeType":"multipart",
   "parts":[
     {
     "mimeType":"multipart",
     "parts":[
         {
            "mimeType":"multipart",
            "parts":[
              {
                "mimeType":"text",
                "body":"ACTUAL CONTENT"
              }
            ]
         },
         {
            "mimeType":"text",
            "body":"ACTUAL CONTENT"

         }
       ]
     },
     {
         "mimeType":"text",
         "body":"ACTUAL CONTENT"
     }
   ]
}
```

If you are interested, it is an email given by Gmail API for Python (simplified).

The objective is to make a list with every part with mimeType="text" which can be inside an arbitrary amount of parts with mimeType="multipart".

Expected result:

```
[
     {
         mimeType: "text"
         body: "ACTUAL CONTENT"
     },
     {
         mimeType: "text"
         body: "ACTUAL CONTENT"
     },
     ...
]
```

I've reached a solution by using an infinite loop and controlling it with breaks:

```
i = 0
while True:
    try:
        if payload["parts"][i]["mimeType"] == "multipart":
            # Add nested parts to the main payload
            payload["parts"].append(payload["parts"][i]["parts"])
            # Remove this part from main payload
            message["payload"]["parts"].pop(i) 
        i = i + 1
    except IndexError:
        break
```

But I think there should be a *Pythonic* or at least more appropriate way to do it.

Comment: What about recursion?

Comment: As a starting point for us, you should post the 'infinite loop' you already wrote. That gives us a better idea of what's going on.

Comment: It would be super-helpful if your mockup was actually a correct JSON, or correct Python code.

Comment: @Cid do you mean recursion? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52850289/loop-over-infinite-nested-dicts-in-python#comment92616309_52850289

Comment: @Chris_Rands me are bad angliche :( Yes I meant recursion

Comment: Just edited the question with my solution and modified the example to be a working Python dict, thanks!

Comment: @Cid don't worry, it was a joke really, I linked to *your* comment ;)

Comment: Did you try your "working Python dict"? :) Anyway, we're done here, just keep in mind for the next time ;)

Comment: @Amadan, sorry not really, I've just done it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, recursion is the key. If we have text, then just return the whole thing as one element; if we have a multipart, add up all the text bits from its parts.

```
def find_text_bits(payload):
    if payload['mimeType'] == 'multipart':
        return [part_text
                for part in payload['parts']
                for part_text in find_text_bits(part)]
    elif payload['mimeType'] == 'text':
        return [payload]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create your own `recursive` function. If you find an object which has `mimeType` property equals to `text` then you have to add it to the `result` *list*. Otherwise, you should `search` in the child *nested object*.

```
payload = { 'mimeType': "multipart", 'parts': [ { 'mimeType': "multipart", 'parts': [ { 'mimeType': "multipart", 'parts': [] }, { 'mimeType': "text", 'body': "ACTUAL CONTENT"} ] }, { 'mimeType': "text", 'body': "ACTUAL CONTENT" } ] }

def search(payload, result):
  for i in range(0, len(payload['parts'])):
    item = payload['parts'][i]
    result.append(item) if item['mimeType'] == 'text' else search(item, result)
  return result

result = search(payload, [])
```

Output

```
=> [{'mimeType': 'text', 'body': 'ACTUAL CONTENT'}, {'mimeType': 'text', 'body': 'ACTUAL CONTENT'}, {'mimeType': 'text', 'body': 'ACTUAL CONTENT'}]
```

Comment: `search(obj['parts'][i], result)` ?